# Exception for each Civi version DB upgrade

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading files from 4.7.18 to 4.7.22, I run the DB upgrade task in:
http://domain.com/civicrm/upgrade/

And then after upgrading to each new version (4 new versions) I get an exception, and then I need to start the upgrade task again. had to do it 4 times. final result looks ok, Civi is upgraded, but how can I avoid these exceptions along the way?

repeating exception:

CiviCRM Upgrade Tasks

```
[Error: undefined]
Exception: "Queue runner must be configured before execution. - onEnd"

#0 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php(106): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()
#1 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(102): CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))
#2 [internal function](): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::onEnd()
#3 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(276): call_user_func((Array:2))
#4 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:4))
#5 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:5))
#6 /home/tamera/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:5))
#7 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("upgrade", "queue", "ajax", "onEnd")
#8 /home/tamera/www/www/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:4))
#9 /home/tamera/www/www/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#10 {main}
```

Comment: [Previous](https://www.drupal.org/node/2155689) [reports](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34728.0) have suggested that clearing the cache before upgrading should fix this.